# Creating exceptions when comparing a variable to a string?

Tags: php, magento

The php code excerpt below triggers "Call for Price" for select manufacturers on our Magento site. So, how do I "exclude" select products from these vendors? For instance, within our manufacturer "XMarks" there are 10 products that I do not want to show "Call for Price" but instead the sale price, list price & add to cart button. How do I do this? I'm a complete beginner. Thank you!

```
<p class="special-price">
<span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?></span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
<?php if($manufacturerName == 'XMarks' || $manufacturerName == 'Maxtor' || $manufacturerName == 'Trixfx' || $manufacturerName == "Oouph" || $manufacturerName == "Groffer" || $manufacturerName == "Wofstern"){ ?>
<span class="olyprice">Call for Price</span><?php }
```

Comment: add more `if()` tests?

Comment: You're code looks incomplete and the question is pretty vague. Maybe update it a bit? And look here on how to [mix conditional PHP in a view](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#112231).

Comment: Working on a (presumably real) magento store is not a project for a complete beginner

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="special-price">
<span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?></span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
<?php 
function callPrice(){ echo '<span class="olyprice">Call for Price</span>';}

switch ($manufacturerName){
       case: 'XMarks'
        if(product != prduct)
        {
           callPrice();
        }
        break;
       case: 'Maxtor'
        if(product != prduct)
        {
          callPrice();
        }
        break;
    ...
```

Comment: That's a really bad design that doesn't scale well and it's hard to maintain. You should find what varies and encapsulate it. And the presence of a `switch` which itself contains `if` clauses begs for a different approach.

Comment: I agree but with the given the lack details hard to come up with the perfect approach.